# Limesurvey: Redirection on wrong port

Tags: php, kubernetes, redirect, traefik, limesurvey

I'm currently working on setting up a LimeSurvey (version 5.1.17) inside a Kubernetes cluster. When trying to access the `/admin/` endpoint it works perfectly, but if I try to reach `/admin` endpoint, I get a 301 moved redirect to `http://<URL>:8080/admin`, which is the port pods are listening to.

I have tried modifying the .htaccess file to rewrite the url from `/admin` to `/admin/` but it didn't do anything, I can't even set a 403 on `/admin`, it will redirect me in any case. I also searched across the code but I couldn't find where was the problem.
It might come from Traefik but it doesn't look like it's modifying urls.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I tried to add a traefik `redirectRegex` rule:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: replacement-middleware
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: "(http:\\/\\/[^\\/]+\\/admi[^\\/])$"
    replacement: "$1/"
```

Works like a charm if I try to reach `/admia` but still redirects to `:8080/admin/` using `/admin`

Comment: Have you ever found the answer?

Comment: Hey, no. It suddenly worked out of nowhere. Absolutely no idea why

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply. I was working on this with a colleague, so i dont know the exact details, but for him a reinstallation from scratch also seemed to fix it. Perhaps the download was corrupt or something. Very unsatisfying solution though...

Comment: One reason could be the index.php file put in the admin/ folder, which redirects to the admin page.

Comment: Yeah I though about that. But why would it redirect on the wrong port ? Here is the code responsible for the redirection:
``header('Location: ../index.php/admin');``